# Specifying Categories up-to Equivalence

Tags: category-theory, monoid, universal-property

Are there references for presenting common categories up-to equivalence using universal properties? I'm familiar with the Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets (ETCS), which provides axioms (mostly universal properties) which determine the category of sets and functions up-to equivalence. Similar projects exist for certain categories of topological spaces, but I haven't seen much work on algebraic categories.

For example, is there a collection of universal properties characterizing the category of monoids in set up-to equivalence? If this were the case, then one could use an unambiguous internal language for the category of monoids.

Comment: Does something like the Freyd-Mitchell theorem count?

Comment: @Randall, that doesn't seem right since the Freyd-Mitchell theorem goes in the opposite direction: it converts an abstract Abelian category into a category of modules over some ring. I want to "present" concrete categories using only properties in the language of categories.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332425/is-there-an-elementary-theory-of-the-category-of-groups) for the case of groups.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank you for the excellent reference!

Comment: See also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352298/could-groups-be-used-instead-of-sets-as-a-foundation-of-mathematics

Comment: @OscarCunningham, this is very nice. I appreciate your effort. One question: what does the axiom of replacement add to ETCS? I thought that all models of ETCS were equivalent as categories.

Comment: @MonadMania No. ETCS is a first-order theory so it must have lots of models (assuming it's consistent). There are some axiomatizations that uniquely classify $\mathbf{Set}$, but they all use some property like cocompleteness which itself requires some preexisting notion of sets.